# How to search a pattern containing hyphens inside man pages?

Tags: man

I'm trying to find a command to search for a pattern containing hyphens inside all man pages.

I've looked at `man man`, and found these 3 options:

> `-K`, `--global-apropos`
>
> Search  for  text in all manual pages.  This is a brute-force search, and is likely to take some time;
>   if you can, you should specify a section to reduce the number of  pages  that  need  to  be  searched.
>   Search  terms  may  be  simple  strings (the default), or regular expressions if the `--regex` option is
>   used.
>
> `-w`, `--where`, `--path`, `--location`
>
> Don't  actually  display the manual pages, but do print the location(s) of the source nroff files that
>   would be formatted.
>
> `-S list`, `-s list`, `t--sections=list`
>
> List is a colon- or comma-separated list of order specific manual sections to search.   This  option
>   overrides the `$MANSECT` environment variable.  (The `-s` spelling is for compatibility with System V.)

I've tried to combine them to search for the pattern `mark-modified-lines` which is a readline option described in `man bash`:

```
$ man -s1 -Kw mark-modified-lines
```

But it doesn't find any page:

```
No manual entry for mark-modified-lines
```

And the command exits with the code `16`.
I thought that maybe the syntax of the command was wrong, but it doesn't seem so, since this command correctly finds the 5 man pages on my system which contains the word `guitar`:

```
$ man -s1 -Kw guitar

  /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg-all.1.gz
  /usr/share/man/man1/ffserver-all.1.gz
  /usr/share/man/man1/ffplay-all.1.gz
  /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg-filters.1.gz
  /usr/share/man/man1/ffprobe-all.1.gz
```

I thought that maybe the hyphens in the word caused an issue.
In `man bash`, I found the `--regex` option which is described as follows:

> `--regex`
>
> Show  all  pages with any part of either their names or their descriptions matching each page argument
>   as a regular expression, as with `apropos(1)`.  Since there is usually  no  reasonable  way  to  pick  a
>   "best" page when searching for a regular expression, this option implies `-a`.

I tried to use this option and replace the word `mark-modified-lines` with the regex `mark.modified.lines`, where the hyphens are themselves replaced with the metacharacter `.` which should match any character:

```
$ man -s1 -Kw --regex 'mark.modified.lines'
```

It still doesn't print any page, while I know that the text is written in the `bash` man page.

The metacharacter `.` in the regex seems to be parsed as expected, since this command:

```
$ man -s1 -Kw --regex 'mark.mo'
```

Prints:

```
  /usr/share/man/man1/x11perfcomp.1.gz
  /usr/share/man/man1/xditview.1.gz
```

And these 2 manpages (`x11perfcomp`, `xditview`) are both matched by the regex `mark.mo`.
More specifically, `man x11perfcomp` contains this line:

```
Mark Moraes wrote the original scripts to compare servers.
^^^^^^^
```

And `man xditview` contains this line:

```
    Mark Moraes (University of Toronto)
    ^^^^^^^
```

However, `man -s1 -Kw --regex 'mark.mo'` doesn't print the bash man page:

```
/usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz
```

While I expected it would, since it contains this line:

```
mark-modified-lines (Off)
^^^^^^^
```

Is it possible to search for a pattern containing hyphens inside the man pages?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`man -K` searches the source code of the manual pages, not their rendered form (as displayed by `man`). Hyphens are encoded `\-`, so you need to search for that:

```
man -s1 -Kw 'mark\-mo'
```

Yes, this is rather obscure. [The `man` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html#OPTIONS) mentions, in the description of the `-K` option, that

> Note that this searches the *sources* of the manual pages, not
>                 the rendered text, and so may include false positives due to
>                 things like comments in source files.  Searching the rendered
>                 text would be much slower.

but using this correctly involves knowing the source representation of the text you’re searching for.

Comment: Obscure? Yes. Also, it's a bug.

Comment: @kubanczyk well, it matches the spec, but yes, I’d agree that the spec is buggy ;-).