# How to search for a string from all the man pages

Tags: grep, string, man

What command would show all lines containing the string “brace expansion” (ignoring case) in the man pages for Bash?

I tried `man -wK . | grep "[Bb]race [Ee]xpansion"` I have got series of "couldn't break line" errors.

Then I tried to search using the command `man -s1 -Kw --regex 'brace expansion'` after reading the query in  [How to search a pattern containing hyphens inside man pages?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477084/how-to-search-a-pattern-containing-hyphens-inside-man-pages)

I got back:

```
/usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz
```

I tried to print the file using `cat` and got all the weird symbols.

Answer (score 4):

When you run the command `man bash` you are opening the documentation in the system's default pager (usually `less`). To skip to lines matching a particular pattern, you can type `/<pattern>`. For example, immediately after entering the man page type in:

```
/brace expansion
```

You should then be automatically taken to the first occurrence. From there you can press `n` to be taken to later occurrences.

Also the `.gz` file extension means that the file is compressed using gzip. You will not be able to read this file directly.

Comment: Great, if you could upvote and accept my answer that'd be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

The result of the search - the man page source files on the system - can be passed back to man in local mode to read each page.

```
man -wK --regex 'Brace Expansion' | sort -u | xargs man -l -P cat | grep -inF 'Brace Expansion'
```

The regex used for the man command search is case-insensitive by default. The list of results from the search is sorted and any duplicates are removed. Then, it is passed back to man using `xargs`. By using the `cat` pager, each processed man page can be printed to the standard output. At that point, the data is a stream of plain text on which grep can operate.

The `-l` option of `man` is used to activate local mode, where it parses a file directly instead of parsing the system's MANPATH.

The `-P cat` option of `man` sets the pager to `cat`. This means the processed man page will be displayed using `cat`.

The `-i` option of `grep` is used for case-insensitive search. The `-n` option prints out line numbers (simply added for convenience). The `-F` option specifies that the pattern is a fixed string.

Answer (score 0):

Taken your original question following command will show you all the lines containing "braces expansion" in the bash man pages:

```
for page in $( man -k bash | awk '{print $1}' ); do
    zgrep -i -n  'brace expansion' $(man -w $page) /dev/null
done
```

Firstly you got a list of man pages corresponding to "bash" in their description, thereafter you iterate through the retrieved list and searching for matching 'brace expansion' string. zgrep(1) will silently uncompress files for you ;)